# Increase SharePoint Execution Timeout in SharePoint Online (Office 365)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, office-365

I have office 365 site and web part added on this site. this web part create a document library. This is a sandbox solution
I want to create 2000 document library using this code snippet as follow:

```
for(i=1;i=<2000;i++)
{
      string LibraryName= "Documents -" + i.ToString();
      CreateLibrary(LibraryName);
 }
```

but after creating 15-16 library it give error:: ***Web Part Error: Sandboxed code execution request failed. Correlation ID: 3131159c-7147-209b-31c1-e5632fa01e46***

Is this error occured for Execution Time out or anything else? can anbody solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to increase the limits. Because there is not server on which you can modify the configs.

The smartest way is to break it into small packets.
Or you can use a Visual web part, that call itself after creating each Document Library.

So there must be opened a browser for that, but it didn't get any timeout. 
It's like pain but it works.